# Hibernate - Constraint Name

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Does anybody knows how to set the constraint name for primary key (PK_[name]) ,check (CK_[Name]),Default [DF_[Name]], Foreign Key (Fk_[Name]) ,Unique ..
by using Annotations or xml config for example  i want that Table  ::::

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (
[ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[USERNAME] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[PASSWORD] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[EMAIL] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
[GENDER] INT NOT NULL ,
[ADDRESS] INT,
[AGE] INT CONSTRAINT DF_tblAccount_Age DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT PK_tblAccount_ID PRIMARY KEY([ID]),
CONSTRAINT UQ_tblAccount_Address UNIQUE(ADDRESS),
CONSTRAINT FK_tblAccount_Gender FOREIGN KEY([GENDER]) REFERENCES GENDER([ID]),
CONSTRAINT FK_tblAccount_Address FOREIGN KEY([ADDRESS]) REFERENCES ADDRESS([ID]) ON DELETE SET NULL,
CONSTRAINT CK_tblAccount_Age CHECK ([AGE] > 0 AND [AGE] <100)
)
```

Translate it into annotation class or [name].hbm.xml ,
does Hibernate support to use constraint name or i must alter the tables 
every time i create a new class ... 
I searched and i find 0 results about constraint names !!

Annotation Class Example :::

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
// -->>Add Primary Key constraint Name Here !! ???
private int id;

@Column(name="Name")
private String name;

@Column(name="Surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name="age")
// -->>Add Check constraint Name Here !! ???
private String age;

@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name="Address" , referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
// -->>Add Foreign Key constraint Name Here !! ???
private Address address;
```

Answer (score 9):

In JPA, you can do this at class level, using `@Table` annotation properties, where you specify constraints names. For primary key `id` mapped to column `id`:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID", name = "PERSONS_PK_CONSTRAINT"))
```

Comment: This does not work for me with hibernate 5.4 and Oracle DB (Oracle12cDialect). @UniqueConstraint works only for columns that are not part of PK.