# How to set the name of a class level jpa check constraint

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I would like to define a constraint in JPA on an entity to make sure that either one of two properties "text" or "title" is set to a non-null value.

For this example, suppose the following Question entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Question {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = true)
private String text;

@Column(nullable = true)
private String title;

}
```

For this class, JPA will  generate the following SQL statement (we need to use the oracle dialect):

```
    create table question (
        id number(19,0) not null,
        text varchar2(50 char) null,
        title varchar2(10,0) null,
        primary key (id)
    );
```

In order to check that either one of the properties is set, I could add a check constraint:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Check(constraints = "TEXT IS NOT NULL OR TITLE IS NOT NULL")    
public class Question {
...
}
```

Now JPA will generate this:

```
    create table question (
        id number(19,0) not null,
        text varchar2(50 char) null,
        title varchar2(10,0) null,
        primary key (id),
        check (TEXT IS NOT NULL OR TITLE IS NOT NULL)
    );
```

On the database side, this will generate a check constraint with a random name like "SYS_C00127157".

In order to assign a meaningful name (for example: *check_title*) to the constraint, I could use this DDL:

```
    create table question (
        id number(19,0) not null,
        text varchar2(50 char) null,
        title varchar2(10,0) null,
        primary key (id),
        constraint check_title check(TEXT IS NOT NULL OR TITLE IS NOT NULL)
    );
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Check(name = "check_title" constraints = "TEXT IS NOT NULL OR TITLE IS NOT NULL")    
public class Question {
...
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The @Check annotation in Java does not offer such a *name* property for the constraint.

Is there any other way to set a name so that the generated DDL will match the expected result?

Comment: The only alternative I know is to define it in the `@Column` annotation like this:

`@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(60) CHECK (status IN ('ACTIVE', 'PENDING', 'INACTIVE')))
private String status;`

But I don't think you can add a specific name to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, unfortunately. If you take a look at how the table generation script is built:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/Table.java#L604

you'll see that the string, which you specify in `@Check` annotation is just wrapped like this:

```java
buf.append( ", check (" )
    .append( checkConstraint )
    .append( ')' );
```

and the generation of a constraint name is given to the database.

In contrast, [a few lines above](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/Table.java#L574), you can find that it's possible to influence the name of the unique constraints. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160370/hibernate-constraint-name) you can find an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.

In my opinion it's also not a good idea to generate the production database from JPA annotations. 
The datamodel usually lives longer than the application and therefore it's good to have the DDL under control.

You should consider to use [FlyWay](https://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) for your database migrations.

Comment: You're right and we do use Flyway for database migrations. However I would like to keep the generated schema as close as possible to the production schema. 

When you define FK constraints, it is possible to set a name. At first glance, setting a name for the check constraint seemed to be similar. As it turns out, it is not that simple.

Comment: But why do want to do this superfluous work that does not generate any value?

Comment: We generate the complete schema from the java code. Developers can then easily create Flyway delta scripts from the generated schema. 

If the DDL is being generated correctly, the developers do not have to modify it or remember that in this special case a name for the constraint needs to be added. 

Instead of seeing it as work that does not generate any value I would rather see it as part of the automated process.

Comment: But then you will not be able to create all the database objects because some of them like the constraint name cannot be configured using JPA.