# Is there a way to name default constraint in hibernate ddl

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using annotations as below in my entity.

```
@javax.persistence.Basic
@javax.persistence.Column(nullable = false )
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BooleanType")
@org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault(value = "1")
private boolean primitiveBoolean
```

Generated Hibernate DDL is as below.

```
[primitiveBoolean] BIT default 1 not null,
```

Is there a way to give a constraint name when generating the default value in the generated DDL like below?

```
[primitiveBoolean]  BIT  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_PrimitiveBoolean] DEFAULT 1,
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164311/7218656
You can try this one

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran thanks for answering but what I am looking is for a defaultConstraint. This one only supports UniqueConstraint as i understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Gavin King through the hibernate forum and posting it [here](https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user/topic/.E2.9C.94.20custom.20name.20for.20a.20defaultConstraint.20in.20generated.20hibern.2E.2E.2E) for reference.